# Can MonoTouch be safely used with Core Audio?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, core-audio

It came into my mind that Core Audio callbacks require very low latency. In my case I'm getting requests for 512 samples at a time, which at 44100Hz means that the callback can at a very maximum, take 11.6 milliseconds to run.

Now, as I understand garbage collection, each collection cycle requires the VM to stop all threads. It is then possible for a garbage collection cycle to interrupt a Core Audio callback, and get glitches.

If so, then it is not really safe to use Core Audio from MonoTouch.

Am I correct in my assumptions? or is this all incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Core Audio render callback is going to be called on a realtime thread which is **very** strict about its deadlines. From the sounds of it, you're occasionally exceeding the render callback's time allowance, and being cut off (which == glitches). While I don't know much about MonoTouch, your guess about GC delays being the culprit does sound like a very likely conclusion.

To give you a sense of just how strict Core Audio render callbacks are, here's some things that are unacceptable in that context:

- Allocating memory
- Waiting on a mutex
- Reading data from disk
- Objective-C messaging

Due to the architecture of Core Audio, render callbacks are going to be triggered very shortly before the audio you produce will be heard. Therefore, even a brief GC hangup could trigger audible glitches.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I did have several problems with my callback which I solved, and now the audio is running fine. But even so I'm worried that in future more complex apps, the GC may stop even the core audio thread for collection. This is obviously not an issue in C/C++, so this is just an exploratory question.

Answer (score 1):

No.  The MonoTouch VM does not appear to be guaranteed to execute code in deterministic time.  Real-time audio callbacks require code (usually compiled native C) whose performance can be strictly bounded in time, including all OS calls and any interpreter overhead.